# shorten javascript/jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a javascript function that makes assigned text alternate between 2 colors, gray, and the color value I set when I run the function.

Here is the code I use. The function:

```
function flashtext(ele,col) {
var tmpColCheck = document.getElementById( ele ).style.color;

  if (tmpColCheck === 'gray') {
    document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = col;
  } else {
    document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = 'gray';
  }
}
```

Then for each unique flash I do (content is generated on the fly):

```
     setInterval(function() {
        flashtext('flashingtext1','#ffffff'); 
        }, 500 );
```

The number `flashingtext`, `flashingtext2` increments with each one added, and the color is set to the color it'll alternate with, in this case white.

Then

```
<span id='flashingtext2'>flash me</span>
```

Is there any way I could trim this whole code down so I don't have to add new javascript for each instance that occurs. So i can just have the function down, then define the rest in the span tag? Something like

```
<span id=flashingtext data=#ffffff> flash white </span>
```

The color I give always alternates between that and gray

Basically, cut out the middle bit.

Note: Using jquery too if that gives an easier way.

Comment: so on the fly, they flash automatically? is there by any chance you want to control these flashes? or they just flash all the time?

Comment: I dont need to control them really, just flash every 500. i control whether they appear using php serverside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the same code to apply to all instances then give the elements a common class, say "flashingtext", so that you can select them as a group, but set the individual colours with an inline style:

```
<span class='flashingtext' style='color: white'>flash me</span>
```

Then have a "gray" class:

```
span.gray { color : gray !important;}​
```

Which uses `!important` so it can override the inline styles.

Then your function can select all elements that have that "flashingtext" class and toggle "gray" on or off:

```
setInterval(function() {
   $(".flashingtext").toggleClass("gray");
}, 500);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yenK9/

If you need to assign an `id` to the spans so that you can select them individually for some other purpose then go ahead, but for this colour thing you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can just toggle classes on the element and have each class set a color

```
setTimeout(function() {
$('#flashText').toggleClass('gray');
}, 500);
```